# Tmux pane switch causes displayed info to change

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux

Has anyone any idea what is going on here. I'm not 100% how to word this problem so my google searching has found nothing so far.

I am using terminal on Mac OSX and just started using Tmux. When I fire up a session I get the first screen shot, then when I create a new pane for side by side development with `<C-b>%` a new pane opens but the old one gets corrupted in some way. See second image.

When I jump back to the first pane with `<C-b>LeftArrow` it returns to show the correct info, but then anything in the right pane gets jumbled.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: When I edit files in vim in the right pane (for example) the text appears in the left pane when I hit return and move to the next line. The colouring suggested it is using the wrong width for the screen?

[image: First Tmuz pane]

[image: Adding 2nd Tmux pane]

[image]

Comment: Did you try disabling *transparent* composition?

Comment: Also [this](http://fideloper.com/mac-vim-tmux), look at the *Tmux* part. If it works, post the instructions as an answer with a link to the original page.

Comment: do you mean to use ```set status-bg default ```? If so, that didn't work.

Comment: this `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` ?

Comment: More info: When I add text in a vim session on the right pane, then hit return, the line appears in the left pane. See updated question.

Comment: I modified the .tmux.conf file to include that line and it is the same.  I have no other settings in there.